# Unable to set XML payload in variable in Mule4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I'm a newbie on Mule4. My input message is XML which isn't being set in variable.

I've tried it with different mime types as well, but doesn't work. It does work however when I'm sending the input in JSON format instead of XML.

I'm using the following XML via postman

```
<Weather>
    <City>London,uk</City>
    <appid>b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22</appid>
    <CIF>CIF20257</CIF>
</Weather>
```

And Configuration XML of my code in discussion is

```
<set-variable value="#[payload.Weather.City]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="b98b3ec8-c1f7-436d-9bcf-49eb0ca8a033" variableName="test" mimeType="application/xml"/>
```

Error being displayed is

> **"javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException - Trying to output non-whitespace characters outside main element tree (in prolog or
>   epilog), while writing Xml. Trace: at main (Unknown)" evaluating
>   expression: "payload.Weather.City".**

Comment: Did you tried creating metadata for mapping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do a set Variable.

1. using the set variable component
2. is using a dataweave transformation.

I have used the second approach and i can see that i am able to set the variable

[image]

here is the complete code for the small sample application :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="23645d25-1194-4fcd-ae19-ffae9b9388f8" basePath="/play" >
        <http:listener-connection host="localhost" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="z_playFlow" doc:id="2ae13c16-4e1e-4203-96c3-9d372ce41c63" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="9fa851c0-a05b-46e1-9ba4-f2433c80d67a" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/setxml"/>
        <set-payload value="&lt;Weather&gt;
    &lt;City&gt;London,uk&lt;/City&gt;
    &lt;appid&gt;b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22&lt;/appid&gt;
    &lt;CIF&gt;CIF20257&lt;/CIF&gt;
&lt;/Weather&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="7d122f45-6025-4fb8-a7d4-e1ec0873f40b" mimeType="application/xml"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="af6467e5-7177-403c-b9c0-62fb816b8f60" >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="var" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---

city: payload.Weather.City]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="8cbdcf0f-8b3e-4645-9475-887b9628bc05" message="#[payload]"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

if you have question on how to define a variable via "transform message" component let me know and i can demonstrate that to you.

---

defining a variable within transform message

1. when you pull in a transform message component the default output type is payload for that. like this
   [image]
2. click on the edit current target (pen) option which will open an selections dialog and under the output dropdown select Variable and supply a variable name:

   [image]

Comment: Although my query has been resolved by changing the output type of the set variable component to java. But i'm still curious to know how variable can be set via transform message.
Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when moving from a Mule 3 mindset to Mule 4. The reason for your error is that the type of your variable is XML, but you are trying to write non-xml to it.

The output of `payload.Weather.City` is the string literal `London,uk` which isn't valid XML. There are a couple of options to resolve this.

1. Output valid XML into the variable

```
<set-variable value="#[City: payload.Weather.City]" doc:name="Set Variable" variableName="test" />
```

This will set the value of the variable as `<City>London,uk</City` which is valid XML

2. Change the type of the variable

If you are just hoping to store the String `London,uk` for use later, then you can explicitly set the output type of the set variable component to java.

```
<set-variable value="#[output application/java --- payload.Weather.City]" doc:name="Set Variable" variableName="test" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, both the solutions work perfectly fine.